# Native outsiders and elemental subtypes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

Do the various elemental native outsiders (ifrit, oread, sylph, etc) have an elemental subtype? For example would an ifrit also count as fire subtype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Those creatures are typically [outsiders](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/creatureTypes.html#outsider) with *only* the subtype [native](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/creatureTypes.html#native-subtype)

The typical [ifrit](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary2/ifrit.html#ifrit), [oread](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary2/oread.html#oread), [sylph](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary2/sylph.html#sylph), and [undine](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary2/undine.html#undine) have only the listed subtype of [native](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/creatureTypes.html#native-subtype) and no other subtypes.

Compare this to, for example, the [fire elemental](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/elemental.html#elemental-fire) that possesses the subtypes [elemental](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/creatureTypes.html#elemental-subtype), [extraplanar](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/creatureTypes.html#extraplanar-subtype), and [fire](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/creatureTypes.html#fire-subtype).